# Netbeans/Maven/Tomcat Deploying to webapps/ROOT in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans, maven

I've been googling on how to get Netbeans 6.9 to deploy to $TOMCAT/webapps/ROOT for while, but can't find any information on how to do it. My application is currently being deployed to webapps/myWarName. I've tried changing my warName in pom.xml (maven war plugin), but that still didn't work.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.

You need to right click your webapp go to Properties -> Run -> and change your Context Path to /ROOT. Also, if your prompted to select Remember Permanently, do so - I couldn't get it working with "Remember in Current IDE Session"

Comment: Please select your own answer then.